# JQuery, function does not see text field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

please don't judge my JS skills, I'm complete beginner in it. =))

So I have a function that register user, But I want to make "create_sample_user" button to fill text fields with some data. This way people can quickly check the website, without typing names, email and so on...

[image]

But the problem is: Register button works fine when I type username and all other fields by my self. But Doesn't work(I assume it just doesn't 'see' the values of the text fields) when I fill them with "create_sample_user" button.

```
function create_sample_user() {
    var button = $("#create-sample-user");
    button.click(function() {
        var ranNum = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        var uname = 'Sample_'+ranNum;
        $("#id_username").val(uname);
        $("#id_email").val(uname+'@'+uname+'.com');
        $("#id_password").val(uname);
        $("#id_password2").val(uname);
    });
}

function register_user() {
    $("#register-user").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/registration/register_user/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {
                username : $("#id_username").val(),
                email : $("#id_email").val(),
                password : $("#id_password").val(),
                password2 : $("#id_password2").val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (data) {
                    alert("User was created");
                    window.location = parsed_data.link;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error");
                }

            }
        });
    });
}
```

## THE ANSWER:

whole thing didn't work because of one character in this line of code:

```
`var uname = 'Sample_'+ranNum;`
```

For some reason `_` character was the problem, and AJAX didn't want take it.
in other words:

```
var uname = 'Sample'+ranNum;
```

This line would do the trick :=)

Comment: very interesting - I will have to read up on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, replace your `create_sample_user()` method with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $("#create-sample-user");
    button.click(function() {
        var ranNum = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        var uname = 'Sample_'+ranNum;
        $("#id_username").val(uname);
        $("#id_email").val(uname+'@'+uname+'.com');
        $("#id_password").val(uname);
        $("#id_password2").val(uname);
    });
}​);​
```

Also, try removing the `function register_user()` function wrapper.

This should do it. It should pop up the success alert box as well (I changed your AJAX URL to use the AJAX echo for jsFiddle):
http://jsfiddle.net/MQ6Cq/4/

UPDATES (since you posted your code - I will update this with bugs as I find them):

- You have two `$(document).ready()` calls now - delete the first one (THIS WAS EDITED)
- You have have to remove the lines `function register_user() {` and the closing brace from around the register user click handler

I made a tiny update to my earlier fiddle, just in case it helps with testing, and changed the request type to "GET". Open your browser's console (F12), right-click and turn on logging for XMLHttpRequests. Then run it and you will see that the AJAX is successfully transmitting the data. I don't know what is wrong with your other stuff but I don't have a server that I can test it on and I'm not getting enough feedback to know what's going on after you try each suggestion (or even if you're trying them). I just hope this helps you solve your problem.

Good Luck! :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve it. My server doesn't see the value's so it's trying to register a user with username:null password:null and so on...

Comment: @Serg when you click the button does the text properly display in the textboxes?

Comment: Yes it does, it works just like yours  http://jsfiddle.net/MQ6Cq/, I posted an image above. I can post the whole js file if it's going to help ...

Comment: did removing that function "wrapper" have any affect? I am running a few tests with it ant it seems to work fine for me once that's been removed

Comment: YEAH It has some effect, now when I press register button, I got this error in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N jquery.js:564
jQuery.extend.parseJSON jquery.js:564
$.ajax.success register.js:67
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery.js:1075
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery.js:1193
done jquery.js:7538
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle I posted - there are no errors in the console when you run it, save for the missing CSS file (which is expected, since we don't have your CSS file)...can you post the rest of your code co I can try to help you find what's causing that error (NOTE: the fiddle I posted now uses your AJAX code as well and functions properly)

Comment: @Serg you can test the AJAX call with jsFiddle - if you look at the fiddle I posted you can see the successful test. I will look at your code now that you've posted it, but from the looks of that code I would venture a guess that the error is in the AJAX and, considering there is nothing wrong with what I've seen so far, there could be an issue with your server

Comment: The thing is: I can register user if I type username password email by my self... and I get the success message and everything works fine..

Comment: That means that there are probably a few more JS issues in there that are messing up your "pipeline" (so I'm going to call it) - basically you have dynamic data that is being halted by some other error on the page preventing something from running (how's that for vagueness? :) I'll try to find some more bugs for you to improve on that)

Comment: @Serg did you try making that second change that I posted in my update? If you did I would like to know if it worked or if you got a new error message, etc. Also, can you update the code you posted to reflect the changes? Thanks :)

Comment: But do you want to know what was really the problem?

Comment: No worries! Yes, I do - what was it?

Comment: I updated the question and added the solution at the end. Thank you again for all your help! Really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2AQW/1/) (simplified version of it)

If you look at the console, you'll see the data is well formatted.

The only thing I see in your code is that create_sample_user() is not called so the click event isn't applied to the button. But I guess you've just omitted to put it in the question

```
create_sample_user();
$('#register-user').click(register_user);

function create_sample_user() {
    var button = $("#create-sample-user");
    button.click(function() {
        var ranNum = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        var uname = $("#id_username").val('Sample_'+ranNum);
        $("#id_email").val(uname.val()+'@'+uname.val()+'.com');
        $("#id_password").val(uname.val());
        $("#id_password2").val(uname.val());
    });
}



function register_user() {
    data = {
                username : $("#id_username").val(),
                email : $("#id_email").val(),
                password : $("#id_password").val(),
                password2 : $("#id_password2").val(),
            }

    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to put my code  to jsfiddle but the problem is I can't check if register button would work, because it makes AJAX callto my server (my computer)

Comment: I removed the ajax part and 'console.log' the data which should be sent to ajax. You can clearly see that the data is correct. Maybe the error is in the ajax part of the script.

Comment: I was thinking the same but, the problem is I can register user if I type everything by my self.... and it works just fine.. just in case I updated the question and posted the whole files

Comment: For testing purposes, disable the check_input() function in the document.ready(). You seem do be doing unnecessary stuff in that function. Maybe the continuous ajax request when a user types his email address is creating a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#create-sample-user").click(create_sample_user);

$('#register-user').click(register_user);

function create_sample_user() {

    var ranNum = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    var uname = $("#id_username").val('Sample_' + ranNum);
    $("#id_email").val(uname.val() + '@' + uname.val() + '.com');
    $("#id_password").val(uname.val());
    $("#id_password2").val(uname.val());

}

function register_user() {
    data = {
        username: $("#id_username").val(),
        email: $("#id_email").val(),
        password: $("#id_password").val(),
        password2: $("#id_password2").val(),
    }

    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: do you mind to tell me what's the difference between my code and your?